# Rails create column with a day of week and two date times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Currently I am building a homepage for my local soccer club and I want to save training times for each team. The training times will look something like this:

Tuesday 18:00-19:30
Thursday 18:30-20:00

What is the best way to store these values inside the database in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating a Practice model, with each practice having a :start and :end attribute, each typed as a :datetime.  If you generate a migration like so:

```
rails generate model Practice start_time:datetime finish_time:datetime
```

That will build a migration for your database, adding the columns you need.  Be sure to run `rake db:migrate` to update your development database.

You would also have to link this new model to your Team model.  The relationship between teams and practices seems to be one-to-many, so you'd add this to your Team class

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :practices
end
```

and add the corresponding relationship to your Practice model

```
class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end
```

(Note the different use of singular and plural class names in these methods.)

You might then build a method within your Practice class to render a formatted date and time range from these two attributes.

```
def practice_time
  formatted_str = start_time.strftime("%A %H:%M") + " " + finish_time.strftime("%A %H:%M")
end
```

You can see more options for the strftime method [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Once you have stored your date information in a logical way, feel free to develop model and/or helper methods to return your data in a more useful form.  You might also consider some add-ons like [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) to make entering and searching for dates easier.

Comment: This sounds like a really good idea. Will test it tonight or tomorrow and mark your answer as correct if it works. But it looks really clean in theory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution(may or may not sounds good to you). Create two time columns each represents From and To timings of a day.for example
for Monday it goes like this in your database

```
|monday_from(time property)|monday_to(time property)|and so on
+--------------------------+------------------------+
```

Hope this helps you.
**Edit:** I considered that the training events are repeated in time regularly, so you don't have to stick to a particular date.

Comment: The database will contain a lot of empty fields if I do it for every day which I do not really like to do.

Comment: That's not a big problem in your case. If you really think this will be a problem, look at NoSQL databases.

Comment: You are right that it is not a big problem. But I do not like the design approach of having multiple empty database columns.

Comment: What if you want to query training based on a starting time or on a particular day?. I thought about flexibility.

Comment: I guess I can do this with the approach of @LazyMonkey too and it is a cleaner approach imho.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save it to the database as a string.

You can also make a new model (or table) with attributes, start time and end time. Then you can save a Time object to the database.

When loading these Time objects, you can create a helper for view to format the time. It can look the following:

```
def format_time(time)
   time.strftime("%A %H:%M")
end
```

Comment: I do not really like saving strings to my database. See @LazyMonkeys answer. This sounds really promising.